# What is the formula for armor/magic resist reduction?

Tags: league-of-legends

As far as I can tell, it's something like this:

```
damage reduction = armor / (armor + 100)
```

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's correct. The calculations are:

[Armour Resist](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Armor): Damage Reduction = Total Armor / (100 + Total Armor)

[Magic Resist](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Resistance): Damage Reduction = Total Magic Resistance / (100 + Total Magic Resistance)

Comment: And despite what it might seem, Armor does *not* have diminishing returns.

Comment: @Raven: That's true, but it's important to remember that a lot of armor is not better than a mix of armor/hp. Because armor boosts your survivability by a percentage of your hp, and most hp items give a flat hp boost, it's often better to buy hp once you have significant armor. I'm sure you already know this, I'm just leaving it here for any other readers.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer I would love for you to explain how Armor doesn't have diminishing returns.  As is clearly stated in the formula, it does have diminishing returns.  A diminishing return means that the more armor you add the less damage is reduced for each point of armor.

Comment: @Steven Oxley -- you're looking at it from the wrong perspective. While the amount of armor required per point of %damage reduction does increase (the diminishing returns you're seeing), the *effectiveness* per point of armor doesn't decrease. I'd open a new question if you'd like to know more -- comments aren't really suited to the indepth explanation a fuller answer would require. Please don't condescendingly assume I don't know what "Diminishing Returns" mean.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10244/why-would-someone-say-that-adding-armor-in-league-of-legends-does-not-have-dimini  Explain away.  I didn't mean to be condescending.  I was just making sure we had a definition of "Diminishing Returns" to work off of.

Comment: @Raven I think your phrasing is slightly off.  In terms of `Effective Hit Points` armor does not have diminishing returns.  In terms of `Damage Reduction` it most certainly does (every point reduces your RoI for the next point).  There are two concepts here and its easy to mistake one for the other.

Comment: @Steven Oxley -- no worries. I'll gladly write up the longer answer for you.  @Tzenes Yes, I agree with you. That is what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score -2):

When it comes to reduction It is indeed diminishing, but when You work out the formula for Ehp (Estimated hp) 1 point of armor actually always gives 1 additional % of hp based on the base hp.

Comment: EHP is 'effective HP', i.e. the amount of damage you can soak up.