# How much armor/MR blocks ...% psysichal/magic damage

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the formula for armor/magic resist reduction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5601/what-is-the-formula-for-armor-magic-resist-reduction)

How more Armor and MR you get, how less % damage you get from it.
But what are the numbers?
Because i made it once to almost 500 armor, and i blocked 82% I believe.

Comment: This question has been answered elsewhere on the site. Please seek the linked duplicate question.

Comment: And a potential followup question about [diminishing returns](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10245/336) might be relevant.